# Window Batch: Testing command line parameters

Tags: batch-file

The following batch file is meant to check if a command line parameter is equal to a certain value.  If so, it should delete one file, if not, another file should be deleted. But it is not working, and neither file is getting deleted. What is wrong?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if %1 == "XXX" # also tried if %1 == "XXX" 
   del BBBB.txt
else
   del CCCC.txt
ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if "%~1" == "XXX" (
   del BBBB.txt
) else (
   del CCCC.txt
)

ENDLOCAL
```